# how to get the order in a list of the most similar string in python

Tags: python, string, compare, sequence, similarity

I want to compare a string with a list of other string and get the most similar. I can do it with difflib in python. But, what I want to do is get the order in the list.

```
from difflib import get_close_matches

a = ['abcde', 'efghij', 'klmno']
b = 'cdefgh'
print get_close_matches(b, a)
```

That code will return `['efghij']` which is right. But, what if I want to get 1 instead, because `a[1] = 'efghij'`?

and, how do I get similarity ratio?
should I compute it again with `SequenceMatcher(None, b, a).ratio()`?

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the first occurrence:

```
>>> ['abcde', 'efghij', 'klmno'].index('efghij')
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Mikes answer is correct, however if speed is necessary and you need many lookups then I would advice you to use a dict:

```
a_hash = dict(zip(a, range(len(a))))
a_hash['efghij'] # prints 1
```

I have never used difflib, but my guess is you would do the following:

```
import difflib
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, b, a[1]).ratio()
# or
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, b, a_hash[difflib.get_close_matches(b, a)]).ratio()
# both returns 0.66666
# presumably because both strings have de and 2/6 = 0.666
```

Is that what you want?